# problems with combining mean() and subset()

Tags: r, csv

I have a quite specific problem. I have a csv-table from which I want to extract data based on two conditions and get the mean() of this. My code for this one is:

```
GDP <- mean(subset(World,World$Year==2013)$GDP_in_USD,na.rm=TRUE)
```

World is my csv table. In the list I have data with different columns from all countries worldwide from 1960-2015. I want to have all values of the column GDP_in_USD from the year 2013 (so one cell per country basically).

When I use this function, I get the error that the values are neither numeric nor boolesh. The weird thing is that a friend of mine gave me the code and it worked on his computer. When I try to reproduce it, I get the error. To read the csv table, I use:

```
World <- read.csv("World2.csv", header=TRUE, sep=delim, dec=dec, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

What could cause the problem?If you need further information, let me know.

```
    structure(list(Country.Year.Zeitraum_NR.Agriculture_value_added_percent_of_GDP.Central_government_debt_total_percent_of_GDP.Cost_to_export_USD_per_container.Cost_to_import_USD_per_container.Employment_in_agriculture_percent_of_total_employment.Employment_in_industry_percent_of_total_employment.Employment_in_services_percent_of_total_employment.Exports_of_goods_and_services_percent_of_GDP.Final_consumption_expenditure_etc_percent_of_GDP.Foreign_direct_investment_net_inflows_percent_of_GDP.Foreign_direct_investment_net_outflows_percent_of_GDP.General_government_final_consumption_expenditure_._of_GDP.GDP_growth_annual_percent.Government_expenditure_on_education_total_percent_of_GDP.Household_final_consumption_expenditure_etc_percent_of_GDP.Imports_of_goods_and_services_percent_of_GDP.Industry_value_added_percent_of_GDP.Inflation_consumer_prices_annual_percent.Lending_interest_rate_percent.Patent_applications_residents_._nonresidents.Research_and_development_expenditure_percent_of_GDP.Services_etc_value_added_percent_of_GDP.Subsidies_and_other_transfers_percent_of_expense.Tariff_rate_applied_simple_mean_all_products_percent.Taxes_on_exports_percent_of_tax_revenue.Taxes_on_goods_and_services_percent_of_revenue.Taxes_on_income_profits_and_capital_gains_percent_of_revenue.Taxes_on_international_trade_percent_of_revenue.Total_tax_rate_percent_of_commercial_profits.Trade_percent_of_GDP.Unemployment_total_percent_of_total_labor_force_national_estimate.GDP_in_USD = c("Afghanistan;1960;1;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;4.132233258;86.77685029;..;..;..;..;..;..;7.024793471;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;11.15702673;..;537777811.91", 
"Afghanistan;1961;1;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;4.453443322;87.0445247;..;..;..;..;..;..;8.097166426;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;12.55060975;..;548888894.58", 
"Afghanistan;1962;1;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;4.878051281;85.36583991;..;..;..;..;..;..;9.349593301;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;14.22764458;..;546666678.04", 
"Afghanistan;1963;1;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;9.171601205;93.49111965;..;..;..;..;..;..;16.86391035;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;26.03551156;..;751111190.76", 
"Afghanistan;1964;1;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;8.88889265;95.2777688;..;..;..;..;..;..;18.05555524;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;26.94444789;..;800000045.51", 
"Afghanistan;1965;1;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;11.25827903;98.89624551;..;..;..;..;..;..;21.41280357;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;..;32.6710826;..;1006666638.22"
)), .Names = "Country.Year.Zeitraum_NR.Agriculture_value_added_percent_of_GDP.Central_government_debt_total_percent_of_GDP.Cost_to_export_USD_per_container.Cost_to_import_USD_per_container.Employment_in_agriculture_percent_of_total_employment.Employment_in_industry_percent_of_total_employment.Employment_in_services_percent_of_total_employment.Exports_of_goods_and_services_percent_of_GDP.Final_consumption_expenditure_etc_percent_of_GDP.Foreign_direct_investment_net_inflows_percent_of_GDP.Foreign_direct_investment_net_outflows_percent_of_GDP.General_government_final_consumption_expenditure_._of_GDP.GDP_growth_annual_percent.Government_expenditure_on_education_total_percent_of_GDP.Household_final_consumption_expenditure_etc_percent_of_GDP.Imports_of_goods_and_services_percent_of_GDP.Industry_value_added_percent_of_GDP.Inflation_consumer_prices_annual_percent.Lending_interest_rate_percent.Patent_applications_residents_._nonresidents.Research_and_development_expenditure_percent_of_GDP.Services_etc_value_added_percent_of_GDP.Subsidies_and_other_transfers_percent_of_expense.Tariff_rate_applied_simple_mean_all_products_percent.Taxes_on_exports_percent_of_tax_revenue.Taxes_on_goods_and_services_percent_of_revenue.Taxes_on_income_profits_and_capital_gains_percent_of_revenue.Taxes_on_international_trade_percent_of_revenue.Total_tax_rate_percent_of_commercial_profits.Trade_percent_of_GDP.Unemployment_total_percent_of_total_labor_force_national_estimate.GDP_in_USD", row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data by posting the output from `dput(head(World))`.  See the [posting guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).

Comment: Most likely the "..." is being interpreted as a character.  Run str(World) to verify the columns are the classes you expect.

Comment: Yeah you could just try mean(as.numeric(World$GDP_in_USD[World$Year==2013]), na.rm=T), see if that fixes it.

Comment: I used the line na.strings to avoid the problem of missunderstanding the NA.
GabrielFGM: The result is NAN, what confuses me even more.

@WeihuangWong: I will add it to the main comment, but due to my long variable names its not very pretty to read.

Comment: @Dave2e: I have the problem, that i dont get a nice table as you would expect (and as I would get from another data sheet). Its more like my data is one big blog, which is basically useless. What could cause the problem?

There is not way on this plattform to send private messages for me as a new user, correct? Otherwise I would just send you the entire table, so you can have a better look at it

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a mess, the columns names are separated by "." and the data is separated by ";".  If your data structure above is called "df" here is a possible solution.

```
# your data from above
# World<-structure(list(Country.Year. ......

#get names and split
names<-strsplit(names(World), ".", fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
#37 names are created but only 35 columns of data exist
#removing the 2 most like errors
names[15]<-paste0(names[15], names[16])
names[24]<-paste0(names[24], names[25])
names<-names[-c(16,25)]

#now split the main body of the table
temp<-sapply(World, function(x){strsplit(x, ";", fixed=TRUE)})
newdf<-as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(temp), ncol=35, byrow = TRUE))
#rename the columns
names(newdf)<-names
#convert the strings to numbers
newdf[,2:35]<-apply(newdf[,2:35], 2, function(x){as.numeric(as.character(x))})
```

Not the most elegant code but is should get you heading in the correct direction.